# Why is std::min failing when windows.h is included?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    int k = std::min(3, 4);
    return 0;
}
```

What is windows doing if I include Windows.h? I can't use `std::min` in visual studio 2005. The error message is:

```
error C2589: '(' : illegal token on right side of '::'
error C2059: syntax error : '::'
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394132/macro-and-member-function-conflict

Answer (score 198, accepted):

The `windows.h` header file (or more correctly, `windef.h` that it includes in turn) has macros for `min` and `max` which are interfering.

You should `#define NOMINMAX` before including it.

---

In fact, you should probably do that even if there were *no* conflict, since the naive definition of the macro shows why function-like macros are a bad idea:

```c
#define max(a,b) ((a)>(b)?(a):(b))
```

If you invoke that macro with, for example:

```c
int x = 5, y = 10;
int c = max(x++, y--);
```

then `y` will not end up with what you expect. For example, it will expand to:

```c
int c = ((x++)>(y--)?(x++):(y--));
```

That expression (unless undefined behaviour kicks in which would be even worse) will decrement `y` twice, not something you're likely to expect.

I basically use macros only for conditional compilation nowadays, the other two major use cases of old (symbolic constants and function-like macros) are better handled with more modern language features (real enumerated types and inline function suggestion).

Comment: One of the reason why MACROS are evil. :D

Comment: I've used a project-wide /D "NOMINMAX"

Comment: @Micka: where did you put this option inside of your project settings ? I have to use the same option, and I don't know where to put ...

Comment: @flaviu2 afair in a "additional commands" field on the page where all compile commands are summarized. But can't check at the moment

Comment: for it was to add : #include <algorithm> + NOMINMAX

Comment: @flaviu2 C/C++ > Preprocessor > Preprocessor Definitions

Comment: Where is "C/C++ > Preprocessor > Preprocessor Definitions" on QtCreator?

Comment: Why people include `windows.h`? What can replace `windows.h` with the advantage of not requiring NOMINMAX?

Comment: It's always MSFT, isn't it? It wasn't enough for them to make me waste 3 CI runs trying to figure out why min() wasn't working, but then they had to go and make ptrdiff_t a different underlying type than std::streamsize, so the template wouldn't compile either. *eye roll*

Answer (score 124):

No need to define anything, just bypass the macro using this syntax:

```
(std::min)(a, b); // added parentheses around function name
(std::max)(a, b);
```

Comment: Thank you, this is the solution that worked for me. 
I am working on a code where I can't simply use NOMINMAX as some part of the code use drawing code from Windows that needs the macros.

Comment: Could you explain why parentheses around magic can defeat the evil macro!? Cool

Comment: I'm not totally sure about all the magic under the hood, but I believe the macro parser is looking to replace exactly "min(", so "min)(" is ignored by the macro parser. And the function name being wrapped with meaningless ()'s doesn't cause any issues outside of macros.

Comment: Neat solution, but doesn't solve for the problem of having a function with the name `min` or `max` (sample use case: implementing a class that fits into the [UniformRandomNumberGenerator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/UniformRandomNumberGenerator) concept).

Comment: Please see Erik's answer, I think it is a better solution. Less hacky, and clearer.

Comment: @ChenOT A function-like macro is defined as an identifier immediately followed by a left parenthesis (N3690/16.3/10). `min` followed by `)` breaks this rule, therefore `min` is not expanded.

Comment: @NikBougalis: You shouldn't be polluting the global namespace with functions like `min` and `max` anyway. If you have to deal with that then you  have to scope the include in a namespace or something.

Comment: @EdS., perhaps you ought to look at the link I provided to understand my comment. I was not discussing polluting the global namespace. But a macro for `min` or `max` can mess up other code (e.g. `class`-scoped `min` or `max`) like the ones the C++ standard *specifies* for things like the `UniformRandomBitGenerator` concept.

Comment: This is also an issue if you have any static functions or methods named min() or max(), since the macro expansion disrupts the declarations.  Better to use the NOMINMAX solution or undefine them.

Comment: @DavidJ Not sure what you mean, it works the same way. This trick is to avoid macro expansion, it will work on static functions or methods just the same.

Comment: This is the best solution

Comment: To the top sir!

Answer (score 53):

My preferred solution is to make the type explicit like so:

```
auto k = std::min<int>(3, 4);
```

This also stops the preprocessor from matching to `min` and is arguably more readable than the parentheses workaround. One problem with the `NOMINMAX` solution is when your code gets reused on the next project, you (or someone else) has to start again asking why this 'working' code doesn't compile anymore.

However to answer the actual question ****why is it failing?****

The `Windows.h` file, includes `windef.h` which defines the following macros:

```
#ifndef NOMINMAX
#ifndef max
#define max(a,b) ((a)>(b)?(a):(b))
#endif
#ifndef min
#define min(a,b) ((a)<(b)?(a):(b))
#endif
#endif
```

The preprocessor essentially expands macros by looking for the sequence of chars in your code including an open parentheses, in this case `min(`. It then does a basic search/replace on your code, so after the preprocessor step your code has become:

```
int k = std::((3)<(4)?(3):(4));
```

The compiler step, which only has this modified code to go on, is then failing when trying to compile `std::(` giving you your error message.

You can also now see how the various fixes/workarounds proposed on this page work:

1. Defining `NOMINMAX` prior to including `windef.h` means these macros won't get defined, and so the compiler can compile `std::min`.
2. Putting brackets around `std::min` means the preprocessor doesn't see the sequence `min(` anymore, and so leaves it alone.
3. Putting in the template parameter means that `min<` also is not a match for the macro.

Comment: I agree, this is the best solution. I was just coming back to give another answer when I saw that someone else beat me to it.

Answer (score 28):

As others mentioned, the errors are due to min/max macros that are defined in windows header(s). There are three ways of disabling them.

1) `#define NOMINMAX` before including header, this is generally a bad technique of defining macros in order to affect the following headers;

2) define `NOMINMAX` in compiler command line/IDE. The bad part about this decision is that if you want to ship your sources, you need to warn the users to do the same;

3) simply undefine the macros in your code before they are used

```
#undef min
#undef max
```

This is probably the most portable and flexible solution.

Comment: Another issue with option 1 is that it simply does not always work.  There might be other windows headers being included elsewhere that actually need it such as gdiplus.h.  In that case option 3 might be your only hope.

Answer (score 17):

Try something like this:

```
#define NOMINMAX
#include <windows.h>
```

By default, windows.h defines `min` and `max` as macros. When those are expanded, code that tries to use `std::min` (for example) will end up looking something like this:

```
int k = std::(x) < (y) ? (x) : (y);
```

The error message is telling you that `std::(x)` isn't allowed.

Answer (score 6):

In my case, project did not include `windows.h` or `windef.h` explicitly. It was using Boost. So, I resolved the issue by going to the project `Properties -> C/C++ -> Preprocessor`, and appending **`NOMINMAX`** in the `Preprocessor Definitions` (VS 2013, VS 2015).

Comment: For VS 2015 defining the macro in the file didn't work for me. Defining in the project worked.

Answer (score 3):

For people including windows.h, put the following in effected headers:

```
#include windows headers ...

pragma push_macro("min")
pragma push_macro("max")
#undef min
#undef max

#include headers expecting std::min/std::max ...

...

pragma pop_macro("min")
pragma pop_macro("max")
```

In source files just #undef min and max.

```
#include windows headers ...

#undef min
#undef max

#include headers expecting std::min/std::max ...
```

Answer (score 3):

To solve this issue I just create header file named `fix_minmax.h` **without** include guards

```
#ifdef max
    #undef max
#endif

#ifdef min
    #undef min
#endif

#ifdef MAX
    #undef MAX
#endif
#define MAX max

#ifdef MIN
   #undef MIN
#endif
#define MIN min

#include <algorithm>
using std::max;
using std::min;
```

Basic usage is like this.

```
// Annoying third party header with min/max macros
#include "microsoft-mega-api.h"
#include "fix_minmax.h"
```

Pros of this approach is that it works with every kind of included file or part of code. This also saves your time when dealing with code or libraries that depend on `min`/`max` macros

Answer (score 2):

```
#define NOMINMAX
```

is the trick to suppress the macro definitions of max and min

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/143208

Answer (score 1):

I'd assume windows.h does define min as a macro, e.g. like

```
#define min(a,b)  ((a < b) ? a : b)
```

That would explain the error message.