# Undefining min and max macros

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

In a source code, I saw that min and max were being undefined.  What could be the reason for that?

```
// remove stupid MSVC min/max macro definitions
#ifdef WIN32
   #undef min
   #undef max
#endif
```

Comment: Maybe the author needed to redefine them? Or they were interfering with actual min/max functions that the author created.

Comment: Perhaps they wanted to remove the stupid MSVC macros for min and max ;-)

Comment: @bblincoe: Or interfering with actual min/max functions declared by the standard library headers.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I guess that's what I was trying to say. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some MSVC header has pre-processor macros to define `min` and `max`. This is bad for many reasons. First, they are not reserved names, second, there are standard library functions with the same names.

So MSVC or whatever was breaking the rules and code by defining `min` and `max` as macros, and the use of `undef` is a work-around to fix that problem.

See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004858/stdmin-gives-error), which shows how the defines can break code.