# Min and max functions with Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, windows-10, file-extension

I have the following code in one of header files (`lib.hpp` file) of my project:

```
#ifndef SLIM_MATHS_LIB_HPP_
# define SLIM_MATHS_LIB_HPP_

namespace slim
{
namespace maths
{

namespace lib
{
template <typename T>
inline T        min(T a, T b); // Many errors on this line (see below)
// Other functions
}
}
}

# include "lib.ipp" // Functions definitions are inside

#endif // !SLIM_MATHS_LIB_HPP_
```

It compiled and worked very well with GCC on GNU/Linux system.

Now I am trying to compile it with Visual Studio 14.0 on Windows 10, and I got plenty of error on `min` function definition line, as following:

> Error C2146   syntax error: missing ')' before identifier
>   'a'   slim3d-core C:\Users\msi\Desktop\SLIM3D\inc\slim\maths\lib.hpp  23
>   Error C2433   'T': 'inline' not permitted on data
>   declarations  slim3d-core C:\Users\msi\Desktop\SLIM3D\inc\slim\maths\lib.hpp  23
>   Error C2365   'T': redefinition; previous definition was 'template
>   parameter'    slim3d-core C:\Users\msi\Desktop\SLIM3D\inc\slim\maths\lib.hpp  23
>   Error C2061   syntax error: identifier
>   'a'   slim3d-core C:\Users\msi\Desktop\SLIM3D\inc\slim\maths\lib.hpp  23
>   Error C2059   syntax error:
>   ')'   slim3d-core C:\Users\msi\Desktop\SLIM3D\inc\slim\maths\lib.hpp  23
>   Error C2146   syntax error: missing ')' before identifier
>   'b'   slim3d-core C:\Users\msi\Desktop\SLIM3D\inc\slim\maths\lib.hpp  23
>   Error C2146   syntax error: missing ';' before identifier
>   'b'   slim3d-core C:\Users\msi\Desktop\SLIM3D\inc\slim\maths\lib.hpp  23

I already successfully compiled it with Visual Studio 14.0 on a Windows 7 system, but `lib.hpp` and `lib.ipp` were respectively named `lib.hh` and `lib.hpp`, so I think it is a system problem from Windows 10 or an extention problem.
Maybe Visual Studio refuse to consider content of `.ipp` file as C++ code, as it doesn't color it as code when I open it. However, as it is included from an `.hpp` file and not directly added to solution, there shouldn't be a difference.

Comment: Just a thought - if you preprocess only with `cl /E`, what output do you see for the `inline T        min(T a, T b);` line?  I ask because if some header has a `#define min(a, b)`, it could be interfering with your version.

Comment: Similar question, though about attempted use of `std::min`, with a helpful answer mentioning `NOMINMAX` [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004858/stdmin-gives-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`min` is defined as a macro in `windows.h`.  Add a `#undef min` line to  your header before declaring your function.

Comment: This is why macros are evil.

Comment: @NeilKirk: even more - why Microsoft Visual C++ is evil: what an insane macro for a commonly used header to define....

Comment: @TonyD It probably goes all the way back to the Windows 1.0 days and taking it out would break too much existing code, something MS seems to want to avoid.  They could change it to opt-in (with a define) rather than opt-out with `NOMINMAX`.