# Strange behaviour of the min macro

Tags: c++, min

When I execute the following code:

```
cout<<min(INT_MAX, INT_MAX+ INT_MAX);
```

I obtain `-2` as the output. Can someone explain why?
Shouldn't the output be the value of `INT_MAX`?

Comment: And what value did you expected to see?

Comment: What do you think the type and value of `INT_MAX+INT_MAX` should be?

Comment: BTW, `min` isn't (or at least shouldn't be) a macro.

Comment: Signed integer overflow is undefined behavior, so there is no guarantee for anything here.

Comment: @hvd [`min` is a macro in MSVC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5004858/995714)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc There's a reason I included the parenthesised bit :)

Comment: With a practical compiler and two's complement form you get wrap-around for the sum, and (2^n/2-1) + (2^n/2-1) ≈ -2 modulo 2^n. With a compiler (or options) that treat most any UB as a free license to do someting unexpected that two or three persons on the planet might regard as an optimization, anything can happen. That's about it.

Comment: You're gonna need a bigger type https://ideone.com/79yTqx ...

Comment: To better see what's going on, simplify. `std::cout << (INT_MAX + INT_MAX) << 'in';` will show you what's happening. It has nothing to do with `min`.

Answer (score 5):

`INT_MAX+ INT_MAX` invokes undefined behavior because signed integer overflow.

C++ Standard :

> If during the evaluation of an expression, the result is not
>   mathematically defined or not in the range of representable values for
>   its type, the behavior is **undefined**.

Comment: You can enable wrapping for signed integers in GCC using [`-fwrapv`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-7.2.0/gcc/Code-Gen-Options.html).