# Creating a DLL with VTK throws syntax error in vtkBuffer

Tags: c++, dll, vtk

I created a DLL project by following this [Microsoft tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=msvc-170), which works fine.

Now, I tried to modify the .h and .cpp files and include a `vtkPolydata` as follows.

SurfaceGeneration.h

```
#pragma once

#ifdef SURFACEGENERATION_EXPORTS
#define SURFACEGENERATION_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define SURFACEGENERATION_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

// Load the playdoh model and the polylines text file
extern "C" SURFACEGENERATION_API void sg_init(
    const std::string data_folder, const std::string _playdoh_filename, const std::string _polyline_filename);

// Apply the surface generation algorithm to the playdoh model based on the polylines in the text file.
extern "C" SURFACEGENERATION_API bool sg_execute();
```

SurfaceGeneration.cpp

```
#include "pch.h" // use stdafx.h in Visual Studio 2017 and earlier
#include <utility>
#include <limits.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "SurfaceGeneration.h"
#include <vtk-9.0/vtkPolyData.h>

// DLL internal state variables: none

void sg_init(const std::string data_folder, const std::string _playdoh_filename, const std::string _polyline_filename)
{
}

// Returns true on success, false on failure.
bool sg_execute()
{

    return true;
}
```

Then, it throws the following 15 errors in `vtkBuffer`:

```
> Error C2589   '(': illegal token on right side of
> '::'  SurfaceGenerationDLL    C:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\vtk-9.0\vtkBuffer.h  222 
> Error C2065   'newArray': undeclared
> identifier    SurfaceGenerationDLL    C:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\vtk-9.0\vtkBuffer.h  222 
> Error C2065   'newArray': undeclared
> identifier    SurfaceGenerationDLL    C:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\vtk-9.0\vtkBuffer.h  224 
> Error C2760   syntax error: ')' was unexpected here; expected
> ';'   SurfaceGenerationDLL    C:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\vtk-9.0\vtkBuffer.h  222 
> Error C2760   syntax error: ')' was unexpected here; expected
> ';'   SurfaceGenerationDLL    C:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\vtk-9.0\vtkBuffer.h  222 
> Error C2760   syntax error: ')' was unexpected here; expected
> '}'   SurfaceGenerationDLL    C:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\vtk-9.0\vtkBuffer.h  222 
> Error C2760   syntax error: ':' was unexpected here; expected
> ';'   SurfaceGenerationDLL    C:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\vtk-9.0\vtkBuffer.h  222 
> Error C3878   syntax error: unexpected token '(' following
> 'expression'  SurfaceGenerationDLL    C:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\vtk-9.0\vtkBuffer.h  222 
> Error C3878   syntax error: unexpected token ')' following
> 'compound_statement'  SurfaceGenerationDLL    C:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\vtk-9.0\vtkBuffer.h  222 
> Error C3878   syntax error: unexpected token ')' following
> 'expression_statement'    SurfaceGenerationDLL    C:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\vtk-9.0\vtkBuffer.h  222 
> Error C3878   syntax error: unexpected token ')' following
> 'expression_statement'    SurfaceGenerationDLL    C:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\vtk-9.0\vtkBuffer.h  222 
> Error C3878   syntax error: unexpected token ')' following
> 'selection_statement' SurfaceGenerationDLL    C:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\vtk-9.0\vtkBuffer.h  222 
> Error C3878   syntax error: unexpected token ')' following
> 'statement'   SurfaceGenerationDLL    C:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\vtk-9.0\vtkBuffer.h  222 
> Error C3878   syntax error: unexpected token ')' following
> 'statement_seq'   SurfaceGenerationDLL    C:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\vtk-9.0\vtkBuffer.h  222 
> Error C3878   syntax error: unexpected token ':' following
> 'expression_statement'    SurfaceGenerationDLL    C:\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include\vtk-9.0\vtkBuffer.h  222
```

How can I fix this?

Note that I used vcpkg to install the VTK package, and I didn't encounter any problem/error with VTK in my console application project.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer.

If you follow the tutorial above, you will find `framework.h` file. The `framework.h` includes `windows.h` which has macros for `min`. This macros causes the error.

To fix this, add `#define NOMINMAX` before `#include<windows.h>`.

More explanation of the error can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5004887/3003216)