# Why does the C++ standard library uses names like '__r' for variables?

Tags: c++

The more I learn about C++ the less sense it makes to me that the C++ standard library source code (where all those `std` functions are implemented) makes heavy use of variable names with `__` prefix. Like `std::addressof()` uses `__r` as its single argument. I tried to get meaningful answers why this is the case (even asked ChatGPT!) but no luck. I know that `__` prefix is reserved and user code cannot use such names. But how could user code collide with, say, the argument name of a function in `std`?! That's what's puzzling to me. Same goes for private members in `std`. Even local variables start with the `__` prefix! What's the point of using `__` prefix in those cases? It's almost like the standard library implementers are suggesting through their practice that somehow hiding implementation details from user code depends on this convention. That, without this practice, users could somehow rely on those names that 'were not intended for them'.

By the way, this makes C++ standard library source code much harder to read. Maybe intentionally so?

Comment: "But how could user code collide with, say, the argument name of a function in std?!" Macros.

Comment: "Macros." ... how? Could you provide an example?

Comment: For fun `#include <Windows.h>` and try to use `std::min` and `std::max` [Why is std::min failing when windows.h is included?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004858/why-is-stdmin-failing-when-windows-h-is-included)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose they would use "normal" identifiers. Suppose the implementation uses `foo` as an identifier. Then you might write this code:

```
 #define foo 
 #include <some standard header>
```

If `some standard header` uses the identifier `foo` bad things might happen.

Thats why for the implementation there are certain identifiers resevered. You must not use them because otherwise there might be conflict. The implementation must use them, otherwise there might be conflict as above.

See here for details: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/identifiers

Comment: Would this still hold after modules become more wide-spread?