# min identifier is not found after adding the library in visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, libraries

I have been implementing a project that uses the external C++ library in the visual studio 2022.

I have added the armadillo library in the `project properties > C/C++ > General > Additional Include Directories > ...armadillo library location.`

I have other additional libraries such as eigen library as well.

I have set the `C/C++ > Precompiled Headers > Precompiled Heaader : Not using Precompiled Headers` .
Then I have tried implementing as `:Use/Yu or Create/Yc` as well.

Here are my code:

```
#include "pch.h" // use stdafx.h in Visual Studio 2017 and earlier
#include <utility>
#include <iostream> 
#include <limits.h>
#include "TxLibrary.h"

// Added C library for the implementation
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

// Added C++ libarary for the implementation
#include <vector>               
#include <algorithm>
#include <iomanip>                  

#include <armadillo>
#include <fstream>                  
#include <string.h>                 

void foo(int x, int y){
  int temp = min(x,y);
}

int main(){
  foo(2,3);
}
```

Full error during build including armadillo library:
`Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State Error C3861   'min': identifier not found.`

Warning after removing `#include <armadillo>` :
`1>WARNING: undefined conflicting 'min' and/or 'max' macros.`

Is this because of armadillo library containing min function?
Or Am I choosing the wrong setting for the Visual Studio for including the directories?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is std::min failing when windows.h is included?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004858/why-is-stdmin-failing-when-windows-h-is-included)

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Hi! I don't have #include <windows.h> included in my project :( but I will try to use their solution and see if that works!

Comment: It's possible that armadillo does include it, not sure what library is this

Comment: I have searched up the Armadillo documentation, and it does have the API called min() but I don't want this library  to interfere with #include <algorithm> or #include<math.h> algorithm is there a good solution for it to guide me?

Comment: are you using `min` or `std::min`? Do you have `using namespace std` somewhere? Please show a [mre] and the full error message

Comment: Sure! I will read all link that you have sent and make sure to ask clearly and full error message! I will be taking sometime to read it! Thank you ! I will be right back :)

Comment: Hi! I have edited it by trying to follow the minimal reproducible example !

Comment: The name of the standard library function is `std::min`, not `min`.

Comment: I suspect that the vast majority of those `#include` directives aren't relevant to the problem.

Comment: Thank you @PeteBecker ! I have included std in front of min and it works. The warning sign still appears after building it. I However, I am sure after adding external libraries, the warning sign appeared. so I was thinking to implement the conditional compilation perhaps..

Comment: I have included in the project properties>C/C++>preprocessor>added "NOMINMAX" and it erased the warning message, even if I have put #include <armadillo> !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use std::min instead of min. Avoid `using namespace std`;

Since macro NOMINMAX works, your other header files may indirectly include `minwindef.h`.

And add `(  )`.

`(std::min)(x,y)` should work for you without adding preprocessor:  NOMINMAX

Comment: Hi! Thank you for the update :) I have tried to avoid using namespace std firstly. I have added ( ) wrapped around std::min. I have removed the NOMINMAX in the pre-processor in C/C++ Visual Studio. Unfortunately, still it shows up the warning sign :(

Comment: I do not have your "pch.h" and  "TxLibrary.h". So, I removed them, and the project built successfully.  By the way, you can convert your solution in the comment into an answer and accept it to close this thread.   It will also help others to solve the similar issue.

Comment: alright! Thank you so much for your help :)