# Templated Struct in C++

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2015, c++14

I have a Struct with Template and there is error at constructor at Structure.

I have developed the code with VS2012, now open the project with VS2015 and I have this issue.

How can I fix it?

```
template<typename It>
Rect_< typename VT<typename VT<It>::value_type>::value_type > BoundingRect(It Begin,It End,int inc=0)
{
            typedef typename VT<typename VT<It>::value_type>::value_type T;
            struct M{
                T x,X,y,Y;
                M():x(std::numeric_limits<T>::max()),X(-x),y(x),Y(X){}
                void operator()(const VT<It>::value_type v)
                {
                    if(x>v.x) x=v.x;
                    if(X<v.x) X=v.x;
                    if(y>v.y) y=v.y;
                    if(Y<v.y) Y=v.y;
                }
            };
            const M m( std::for_each(Begin,End,M()) );
            return inc? Rect_<T>( m.x-inc, m.y-inc, m.X-m.x+inc*2, m.Y-m.y+inc*2 ):Rect_<T>( m.x, m.y, m.X-m.x, m.Y-m.y );
}
```

The error is at this line

```
M():x(std::numeric_limits<T>::max()),X(-x),y(x),Y(X){}

as C2589 '(':illegal token on right side of '::'
   C2059 syntax error: ':
```

How to fix the errors?
:'

Comment: Have you added `limits` header ? [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561368/illegal-token-on-right-side-of) may be helpful.

Comment: @rafix07 thanks let me try.